# React - change view when we click on img

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I woudlike to change a view when I click on my img :

```
const imageClick = () => {
  console.log('Click');
}

const Next = () => {
  
  return (
        <Heading size="xl" mb="24px">
          <br/>
          <Row>New Feature Launched</Row>
        </Heading>
          <Row><img
            src={img}
            onClick={() => imageClick()}
            loading='lazy'
            alt=''
          /></Row>
        <br/>
```

I wouldike to go there after clicked : http://localhost:3000/view/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into my experiment

https://codesandbox.io/embed/simple-route-pgxw4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

full sample above is implementation the react route, you can move from View 1 to View 2

Answer (score 1):

Look into a form of routing like react-router-dom

https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Then you can simply use `<Link to="/view1">Home</Link>`